# Как получить сколько часов осталось до конца дня?

Tags: javascript

сейчас получаю сколько прошло с начала дня

```js
function func() {
  let now = new Date();

  let today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

  let diff = now - today; // разница в миллисекундах
  return Math.round(diff / 3600000 ); // получаем часы
}

alert( func() );
```

Comment: Т.е. получить сколько прошло - можете, а из 24 вычесть это число - не можете?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, это понятно
но как задать это

Comment: @elka, Есть принцип программирования KISS. Вот его в ответе я и применил. И вам так же действовать советую в таких ситуациях.

Comment: @elka где задать? кому задать? зачем что-то задавать?

Answer (score 0):

На JS не пишу, но полагаю, что так, как написано, результат верный будет:-)
Из 24 часов в миллисекундах вычтем, сколько уже прошло.
Для ясности детально показал, как считаю, но можно заменить константой.

```
function func() {
  let now = new Date();

  let today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

  let diff = 24*60*60*1000 - (now - today); // разница в миллисекундах
  return Math.round(diff / 3600000 ); // получаем часы
}

alert( func() );
```

Comment: @elka, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Еслиответ полностью решил задачу - приниять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). Или написать, если не помогло по какой-то причине.